# Storing Data using sessionStorage in javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

What I trying to do is to store the user data as he types on the webpage into session storage. So that if the user refreshes the page data will presist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p id = 'name' contenteditable="true">Riya Sharma</p>
        
    </div>
</body>
<script src="sessionstorage.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here is js file:

```
if(typeof Storage !== 'undefined'){
    const element = document.getElementById('name');

    element.addEventListener("keydown" , function(event){
        var text = document.getElementById('name').textContent;
        sessionStorage.setItem("store", text);
    });
    document.getElementById('name').textContent = sessionStorage.getItem('store');
}else {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

The problem is When I run an HTML file it is not displaying anything(not able to figure out why?)
And second is when I type something and refreshes the page then it is not displaying the last character(which is very weird)

Comment: When you say "not displaying the last word", did you mean "last character"? That would make more sense, since your event listener is running before the key is processed.

Answer (score 0):

If the snippet below shows `Awaiting Script Result` then you should make sure JavaScript is enabled in your browser. Be aware that `sessionStorage` lasts until the page (with an `x`) is closed but `localStorage` stays until the browser clears its cache.

```js
document.querySelector('#support').innerText =
  'sessionStorage' in window ?
    'Supported' :
    'Not Supported'
```

```html
<div id='support'>Awaiting Script Result</div>
```

A side note is that your code won't work with `keydown`, you should use `keypress`. The `keypress` is called after the key is pressed, which allows time for the letter to be included the `<p></p>`.

Comment: I tried keypress also but the same thing happening not displaying the last character.

Comment: @NitinSaini, make sure you are **NOT** calling `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: No, the above file is the only code I have written fornow